# Soy nuevo, ¿cuál es la manera más sencilla de subir mi reputación?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Muchos usuarios nuevos seguro se preguntan: ¿Qué debo hacer para subir mi reputación?

Recuerdo que cuando empecé hace un mes en Stack Overflow en español tenia una puntuación de 1. Tenía algo de conocimiento sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina, pero me preocupaba que por mi falta de reputación mis respuestas no fueran tomadas en cuenta, o que al hacer una pregunta no tuviera ninguna respuesta. Fue duro, pero a pesar de eso logré ganar algo de reputación.

Ahora me gustaría preguntar a los usuarios más experimentados si es que pueden dar algunas recomendaciones a los usuarios nuevos para subir su reputación.

Comment: 1. Formatea bien tus publicaciones, sé cuidadoso con los que te leen: si no escribes bien, dificilmente se te leerá bien. 2. No presupongas nada: _me preocupaba que por mi falta de reputación mis respuestas no fueran tomadas en cuenta, o que al hacer una pregunta no tuviera ninguna respuesta._ Luego dices _Fue duro, pero a pesar de eso logré ganar algo de reputación_. En mi experiencia, este "a pesar de eso" no tiene sentido, ¿fue al contrario en tu caso?.

Comment: También me interesa saber un poco más de por qué "*fue duro*"

Comment: Hola, dije _Fue duro_ por que sabia que para ganar puntos debía esforzarme en mis respuestas, también la mayor parte de las preguntas que encontraba eran muy complicadas de responder, era difícil encontrar preguntas que pueda responder y ganar puntos.

Comment: La reputacion es una demostracion de que tan confiable te ve la comunidad. Eso no quiere decir que las respuestas de alguien que tenga 1 de reputacion sean malas, si no que se le tiene menos "confianza"en cuanto al manejo del sitio. Yo (y creo que varios de aca), no dudamos de la calidad de nadie, tenga la reputacion que tenga. Si podemos llegar a dudar si vas a editar una publicacion, pero a la hora de contestar, todos somos iguales.

Comment: cualquiera que sea usario de SoEs puede responder!debes  tener en cuenta que la mayoria empezamos de esa forma , yo muchas veces fui regañado, tambien votaron -1 , al final aprendi a respetar las reglas y me ha ido de maravilla;  hace unos dias le recomende a un usuario con 14 K editar su respuesta, el amablemente respeto mi comentario y lo hizo no porque tenga mas puntos si no que nos basamos en generar respuestas muy utiles y muy buenas

Comment: Si haces preguntas/respuestas claras y de calidad conseguirás puntos muy fácilmente. Con claras y de calidad me refiero a: (**en preguntas**) exponer bien claro lo que necesitas y dónde estás encontrando el error. Y lo más importante, dejar código que sea relevante para poder resolver la pregunta. (**en respuestas**) Que tengan una explicación clara de porque el código que aportas le puede ayudar al OP, no supongas nada y no contestes preguntas que no muestran ningún esfuerzo (se deben cerrar). Si puedes dejar referencias oficiales a la explicación mucho mejor. La reputación llegara sola!! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ¿Qué debo hacer para subir mi reputación?

Mi consejo es, por experiencia primeramente leer los documentos del [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), te lo comento porque me tuve un momento de frustración cuando mis preguntas y respuestas eran votadas negativamente o eliminadas, para mi es un punto clave e importante seguir lo definido en el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Considera que puedes obtener reputación:

- **Respondiendo preguntas**, [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
  Si el contenido de una respuesta ayuda a resolverla problemática planteada en la pregunta, el OP te agradecerá votando como correcta tu respuesta y por lo tanto obteniendo reputación de +15 e incluso +2 para quien "acepta" la respuesta.
- **Realizando preguntas**, [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si creas una buena pregunta también obtendrás reputación por esto, cuando es votada a favor, +5.
- **Incluso si tienes menos de 1000 de reputación, como es tu caso, puedes sugerir ediciones las cuales si son aceptadas puedes obtener +2 de reputación.**

> [**¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)
>
> La reputación es
> una medida aproximada de cuánto la comunidad confía en ti; se gana
> convenciendo a tus pares (los otros miembros de https://es.stackoverflow.com) de que sabes
> de lo que está hablando. El uso básico del sitio, incluyendo hacer
> preguntas, responder y sugerir ediciones, no requiere ninguna
> reputación en absoluto. Pero cuanto más reputación ganas, más
> privilegios te son otorgados.

**No importa si un usuario tiene poca reputación, te puedo comentar que varios miembros de la comunidad hemos obtenido excelente información de respuestas de nuevos usuarios o con poca reputación, la reputación no debe ser tomada en cuenta para determinar una buena pregunta/respuesta, en este caso el contenido es lo verdaderamente importante.**

Comment: Yo nunca leí nada de lo que hay en **Centro de ayuda**, ni las indicaciones. Tan sólo tengo una pizca de sentido común.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz el sentido común es el menos común de los sentidos. Muchos usuarios acaban con preguntas cerradas y negativos (especialmente al principio ), cuando si se hubieran leído y seguido los consejos de [ask] o [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](/help/mcve) habrían obtenido resultados completamente diferentes. Incluso usuarios con más experiencia ( ) podrían beneficiarse de leer esas dos páginas (no todo el [help], sólo esas dos y el [answer]). A veces al sentido común le hacen falta la experiencia y el conocimiento que aporta leer algún artículo del Centro de ayuda.

Answer (score 6):

A lo recomendado por Jorgesys, que en síntesis es leer la ayuda, cabe agregar que también ayuda leer Meta y participar una vez obtenido 5 puntos de reputación.

Nótese que el nivel de 5 puntos de reputación se superan al obtener tan solo un voto positivo en una pregunta, aceptar dos respuestas a preguntas propias, o un voto positivo en una respuesta, esto asumiendo que no haya votos negativos.

Por otro lado, las publicaciones de usuarios con rep 1 pasan por una cola de revisión especial que es una forma que tienen los sitios de Stack Exchange de ayudar a los usuarios a entrar en contacto con usuarios más experimentados en el funcionamientos del sitio con sus primeras publicaciones.

Es usual que a los nuevos usuarios en sus primeras publicaciones se les recomiende realizar el recorrido, revisar artículos de ayuda y usar las etiquetas apropiadamente. Esto les ayudará a ganar sus primeros puntos de reputación.

Answer (score 4):

> *me preocupaba que por mi falta de reputación mis respuestas no fueran tomadas en cuenta*

Nadie vota (edito: nadie debería votar) una respuesta positivamente simplemente porque su autor tenga ya mucha reputación, la relación causa efecto es al revés: hay usuarios con mucha reputación porque dan buenas respuestas a menudo.

Comment: ¿Nadie, nadie, nadie? Resulta difícil de creer.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Bueno, no puedo generalizar, pero en general uno lee una buena respuesta y la vota. Yo muchas veces ni me molesto en ver de quién es la respuesta porque no conozco a casi ningún usuario fuera de los habituales del chat

Answer (score 3):

No se que para que exactamente quieres ganar más reputación, yo al principio empecé a subir porque me gusto mucho el sistema de puntos gamificado y la verdad, aunque tenía ya unos años en stack no había participado mucho por la barrera del idioma y porque era más de buscar soluciones que preguntar o responder y el desarrollo me gusta, pero no soy un experto (ya que yo soy Diseñador Gráfico Profesional y lo mío es más diseñar y prototipar), pero como tuve un mes de descanso y vi una pregunta muy sencilla de responder en un lenguaje que me fascina y siento que domino mucho (el genial lenguaje de formato **`CSS`**) al cabo de un tiempo y sin darme cuenta había respondido casi 50 preguntas y creo que bien respondidas, porque de no tener sino como 5 puntos pase a casi 300 y desde Diciembre acá, no se exactamente como, pero me volví adicto a responder y en marzo ya tenía 2000 puntos, que no es mucho comparado con muchos expertos, pero para mi es todo un logro.

Así que si tengo algo que aconsejar, sería:

> Responde detalladamente en un o dos temas o **lenguajes que consideres que
>   dominas o sabes mucho.** Además usa bien el sistema de ayuda y usa las etiquetas para filtrar las preguntas que más dominas.

Está demás lo siguiente, pero trata siempre de hacerlo con paciencia y como si cualquier persona sin muchos conocimientos en el tema pueda entenderte, revisa los comentarios de las personas que están ayudando también, sobretodo los moderadores que son un ejemplo y si quien pregunta, respondió un comentario, trata de ampliar la pregunta una vez entiendas donde y como se soluciona su problema.

Comment: Hola, gracias por participar, respondiendo a **para que se quiere ganar mas reputación**, todos los usuarios nuevos no cuentan con los mismos privilegios que el resto de la comunidad, deben ganárselos a través de la formulación de buenas preguntas y respuestas. La pregunta no esta formulada con el fin de acumular gran cantidad de reputación sin una buena razón, sino ganar la suficiente reputación para obtener los privilegios básicos y poder participar a la par de los demás usuarios, creí haber sido muy explicito en la pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Un ejemplo: Para comentar CREO que se necesita al menos 50 puntos de reputación.

Answer (score 3):

En mi experiencia, la mejor forma de ganar reputación es respondiendo de forma clara y concisa las preguntas y haciendo preguntas claras y que denoten un buen esfuerzo previo (lee [este artículo](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), o [su traducción al español](https://medium.com/@unrob/que-has-intentado-12b31d36bc89)).

Si eres bueno en un tema, responde preguntas de ese tema. No necesitas ser un gurú, sólo necesitas ser claro (un ejemplo: la respuesta por la que más votos positivos he recibido en SO en inglés es [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029441/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-in-sql-where-id-x-to-y/16029501#16029501), y creo que no es algo sofisticado).

Yo no soy un programador profesional... pero creo que puedo aportar mi grano de arena a la comunidad.

La reputación no tiene que ser un objetivo en sí misma... Sí, es padre ver como sube, pero creo que lo principal es aportar. Y al aportar a la comunidad generas círculos virtuosos: mas programadores obtienen soluciones, votan por las mejores, y la reputación sube, lo cual motiva a dar mejores respuestas a nuevas preguntas.

En resumen: buenas respuestas y buenas preguntas son la mejor forma de ganar reputación... y ni tus respuestas ni tus preguntas deben ser eruditas, sino honestas y claras.

Toma tiempo, pero se puede subir alto ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yo mismo soy nuevo en SO (23/10/2021). Compartiré brevemente mi opinión y la experiencia obtenida:
El objetivo es el desarrollo mutuo. Los conocimientos de unos disponibles para quien lo necesita. No podemos saberlo absolutamente todo, pero al unirnos creamos una "Mente casi perfecta", podemos resolver casi cualquier dificultad.
Para preguntar:
Esto es como una escuela, luego de realizar una investigación concienzuda y no encontrar solución, preparas tu pregunta; la revisas y publicas. Alguien compartirá su tiempo y conocimientos, eso vale, y si es correcto, recibe reputación.
Para responder:
Es necesario tener presente que, los mejores resultados se logran con la preparación, no se habla de lo que no se sabe. Es mejor prepararse en algún tema,  y buscar a alguien que te necesite en lo que tú dominas bien, así garantizas subir de nivel, y ayudas mucho. Éxitos!!