# ¿Por que superar los 50 de reputación es complicado?

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, reputación

Me he dado cuenta con varias cuentas que tengo en StackExchange y en cuentas de otros usuarios que me he fijado que entre la reputación de 20 y d 50 siempre es más complicado crecer.

> ¿Por qué los grandes perfiles puntúan tan mal las preguntas de estos
>   perfiles cuando suelen ser nuevos usuarios con poca experiencia?
>
> ¿No sería mejor orientarlos para poder seguir aportando a la
>   comunidad?
>
> ¿Algún consejo de errores comunes de estos usuarios que ya tienen la
>   confianza de haber resuelto alguna duda y se relajan al formular más
>   preguntas?

Un saludo.

Comment: No estoy muy de acuerdo con tu observación. Es cierto que en el sitio se vota menos de lo que debería, pero eso afecta tanto a usuarios de alta reputacion como a los que no. Te aseguro que si  haces una buena pregunta/respuesta, pasar de 50 de reputación no es complicado. En tu caso veo que solo has realizado una pregunta en el sitio, y ha sido valorada positivamente.

Comment: @Pikoh es simplemente una impresión mía. Recientemente he tenido que eliminar mi cuenta de Stack y volver a crearla porque no me permitían hacer nuevas preguntas. Una cosa muy curiosa y que me penalizó a mi bastante es que cometí el error de que sin poder comentar (al no tener la reputación suficiente) escribí una respuesta que luego fue muy mal votada tirándome por los suelos la reputación que ya tenía. Este tipo de cosas uno no es consciente hasta que no pasa por ello, por eso escribo este post de cara a obtener algunos consejos.

Comment: Todos hemos empezado por ahi. Si recibes muchos votos negativos en una respuesta, simplemente eliminándola haces que esos votos no te resten (y puedes,de hecho,ganar una [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) incluso). En realidad, toda la información necesaria está en las [páginas de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Es realmente muy sencillo lograr 50 puntos, ni siquiera necesitas saber programación, tan solo haciendo 25 ediciones que valgan la pena (gramática, formato, puntuación y ortografía).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te pido no desesperes, revisando tu actividad en el sitio veo que hace poco iniciaste en SOes y la primera publicación tuvo buen recibimiento en la comunidad.

Te sugiero continúes por el mismo camino, revisa además que opciones tienes para conseguir reputación:

[Soy nuevo, ¿cuál es la manera más sencilla de subir mi reputación?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3388/soy-nuevo-cu%C3%A1l-es-la-manera-m%C3%A1s-sencilla-de-subir-mi-reputaci%C3%B3n/3389#3389)

> - **Respondiendo preguntas**, [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Si el
>   contenido de una respuesta ayuda a resolverla problemática planteada
>   en la pregunta, el OP te agradecerá votando como correcta tu respuesta
>   y por lo tanto obteniendo reputación de +15 e incluso +2 para quien
>   "acepta" la respuesta.
> - **Realizando preguntas**, [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si creas una
>   buena pregunta también obtendrás reputación por esto, cuando es votada
>   a favor, +5.
> - **Incluso si tienes menos de 2000 de reputación (mientras que no tengas el privilegio [Editar Preguntas y
>   Respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)), como
>   es tu caso, puedes sugerir ediciones las cuales si son aceptadas
>   puedes obtener +2 de reputación.**

Es importante revises también:

> [**¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

#### Recuerda que obtener reputación te puede ayudar a [**obtener privilegios**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) y  contribuir más en el sitio!

Answer (score 4):

No es difícil superar ese límite en la medida que sigas las reglas

- has preguntas interesantes y que aporten a la comunidad sobre dudas claras de programación
- no respondas a preguntas basadas en opiniones o que sólo piden se les resuelva algo
- cuando respondas no solo pongas la teoría de cómo resolverlo, en su lugar aporta el código mínimo necesario
- si vas a responder con enlaces coloca lo relevante de los Mismos en tu respuesta, pues solo poner el link es visto como un aporte de baja calidad

Cuando se siguen estas reglas es simple crecer en reputación, por el contrario a los nuevos siempre se les orienta con enlaces oficiales para que mejoren sus aportes pero no todos quieren

Es tan simple notar a un usuario que no ha leído la guía de cómo preguntar o el tour mismo, cuando dice que SO en español es un foro, cosa que es incorrecta

La zona de respuestas no es espacio para hacer preguntas similares o pedirle aclaraciones al OP, cosa que los nuevos usuarios hacen con frecuencia; se les vota negativo pero si la eliminan o editan y la vuelven una respuesta útil entonces podrán recibir votos positivos